# How do I select rows in a data frame before and after a condition is met?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm searching the web for a few a days now and I can't find a solution to my (probably easy to solve) problem.

I have huge data frames with 4 variables and over a million observations each. Now I want to select 100 rows before, all rows while and 1000 rows after a specific condition is met and fill the rest with NA's. I tried it with a for loop and if/ifelse but it doesn't work so far. I think it shouldn't be a big thing, but in the moment I just don't get the hang of it.

I create the data using:

```
foo<-data.frame(t = 1:15, a = sample(1:15), b = c(1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1), c = sample(1:15))
```

My Data looks like this:

```
ID    t   a   b   c
1     1   4   1   7
2     2   7   1   10
3     3   10  1   6
4     4   2   1   4
5     5   13  1   9
6     6   15  4   3
7     7   8   4   15
8     8   3   4   1
9     9   9   4   2
10   10   14  1   8
11   11   5   1   11
12   12   11  1   13
13   13   12  1   5
14   14   6   1   14
15   15   1   1   12
```

What I want is to pick the value of `a` (in this example) 2 rows before, all rows while and 3 rows after the value of `b` is >1 and fill the rest with NA's. [Because this is just an example I guess you can imagine that after these 15 rows there are more rows with the value for `b` changing from 1 to 4 several times (I did not post it, so I won't spam the question with unnecessary data).]
So I want to get something like:

```
ID    t   a   b   c   d
1     1   4   1   7  NA
2     2   7   1   10 NA 
3     3   10  1   6  NA 
4     4   2   1   4   2
5     5   13  1   9  13 
6     6   15  4   3  15 
7     7   8   4   15  8
8     8   3   4   1   3
9     9   9   4   2   9
10   10   14  1   8  14 
11   11   5   1   11  5
12   12   11  1   13 11 
13   13   12  1   5  NA 
14   14   6   1   14 NA 
15   15   1   1   12 NA
```

I'm thankful for any help.

Thank you.

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: I don't understand the question. Presumably column `d` is based on your "condition", but column `d` is identical to column `a` except for its first and last entries, is it not? How does `b` play a role here? Can you please clarify on the condition of your specific example?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, it's my first question. I tried to reduce the data in the example as much as I could, so I'm afraid it looks not very reasonable. 
My Data comes from experiments in which `b` is an LED that switches on (4) and off (1) and I want to calculate the rolling average of 10 values of `a` just before the LED is on (100 values), while it's on and 1000 values after the LED is off. It looks different when there are the half of a million observations.

Comment: If the answer from @missuse doesn't address your question, could you please give a *representative and minimal example*, where you state the condition(s) for your test case and the expected outcome. I imagine that would help a lot with clarifying your problem to the SO community.

Comment: I edited the question a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt.

Get indexes that satisfy the condition `b > 1`

```
z <- which(foo$b > 1)
```

get indexes for `(z - 2) : (z + 3)`

```
ind <- unique(unlist(lapply(z, function(x){
  g <- pmax(x - 2, 1) #if x - 2 is negative
  g : (x + 3)
})))
```

create `d` column filled with `NA`

```
foo$d <- NA
```

replace elements with appropriate indexes with `foo$a`

```
foo$d[ind] <- foo$a[ind]
```

Comment: Thank you! I think that should work well, unfortunately it doesn't  on the real data by now. But I will work it out. At first it was the Error `only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts` and after I subsetted the data frame to reduce it a little bit it gives an replacement error, which I don't understand yet. But your solution brings me some steps forward!

Comment: @Chris If you could provide the data, I would not mind downloading half a million rows to give it a try in providing a solution. Check if it works now tho. I have added an additional condition in the `lapply` call.

Comment: I was busy the last days coping with life, but now I got time for work again. :D
Thank you alot @missuse! Your answer helped me to solve the problem. At first I ran into the problem that the replacement would have been larger than the actual dataframe (due to the +1000 rows in my real data). In the example it would be equvalent to `x+7`.  I solved it now. I added `h <- ifelse(x+7 > nrow(foo), nrow(foo), x+7` and then go with `g:h`. I don't if it's a good solution, but for now I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 2):

here is the same attempt as missuse, but with data.table:

```
library(data.table)
foo<-data.frame(t = 1:11, a = sample(1:11), b = c(1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1), c = sample(1:11))
DT <- setDT(foo)
DT[ unique(c(DT[,.I[b>1] ],DT[,.I[b>1]+3 ],DT[,.I[b>1]-2 ])), d := a]

     t  a b  c  d
 1:  1 10 1  2 NA
 2:  2  6 1 10  6
 3:  3  5 1  7  5
 4:  4 11 4  4 11
 5:  5  4 4  9  4
 6:  6  8 4  5  8
 7:  7  2 4  8  2
 8:  8  3 1  3  3
 9:  9  7 1  6  7
10: 10  9 1  1  9
11: 11  1 1 11 NA
```

Here

```
unique(c(DT[,.I[b>1] ],DT[,.I[b>1]+3 ],DT[,.I[b>1]-2 ]))
```

gives you your desired indixes : the unique indices of the line for your condition, the same indices+3 and -2.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Sadly it says i is out of range. So it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# example dataset
foo<-data.frame(t = 1:15, 
                a = sample(1:15), 
                b = c(1,1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                c = sample(1:15))

# function to get indices of interest
# for a given index x go 2 positions back and 3 forward
# keep only positive indices
GetIDsBeforeAfter = function(x) {
  v = (x-2) : (x+3)
  v[v > 0]
}


foo %>%                        # from your dataset
  filter(b > 1) %>%            # keep rows where b > 1
  pull(t) %>%                  # get the positions
  map(GetIDsBeforeAfter) %>%   # for each position apply the function
  unlist() %>%                 # unlist all sets indices
  unique() -> ids_to_remain    # keep unique ones and save them in a vector

foo$d = foo$c                  # copy column c as d
foo$d[-ids_to_remain] = NA     # put NA to all positions not in our vector

foo  

#     t  a b  c  d
# 1   1  5 1  8 NA
# 2   2  6 1 14 NA
# 3   3  4 1 10 NA
# 4   4  1 1  7  7
# 5   5 10 1  5  5
# 6   6  8 4  9  9
# 7   7  9 4 15 15
# 8   8  3 4  6  6
# 9   9  7 4  2  2
# 10 10 12 1  3  3
# 11 11 11 1  1  1
# 12 12 15 1  4  4
# 13 13 14 1 11 NA
# 14 14 13 1 13 NA
# 15 15  2 1 12 NA
```